# how to make event_base_loop run continously

Tags: c++, c, events, event-loop

I trying to make a program which reads data on a file descriptor in a call back generated by  the event. but once its reads the data it exits i.e the event_base_loop() runs only once i want it to run again when it reads the data.Right now i am accomplishing it using a global event and then calling add_event() again in the call back function

```
 struct event *ev1;    //this is the global event variable
 void Cb(evutil_socket_t fd, short what,void * arg)
 {
      char buffer[256];
      int rc= recv(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
      printf("DATA = %s\n",buffer);
      event_add(ev1,NULL);
  }

  void Create_UDP_Socket_Event(int fd)
  {
    struct event_base *base = event_base_new();
    base = event_base_new();
    ev1 = event_new(base, fd,EV_READ, cb ,(char *)"");      
    event_add(ev1,NULL);
    int res=event_base_loop(base,0);   
  }
```

As i have to make a dynamic code which will have several udp sockets so i cant use this approach I am using fedora 17 and my compiler is g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the OS and version of your compiler

Comment: @itsols i hve edited it